# drag and drop animate shadow back to original position if not dropped to target

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have made the functionality of drag and drop using ondraglistener. Its working fine But my problem is the shadow which is made does not go back to original image if the view is not dropped at the target. how to animate going of shadow from the position to original position.any help

Answer (score 1):

We have to write our own logic to move it to back, this is what we do.

Add a OnDragListener  to your root view,
in onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) of the dragged View wait for ACTION_DRAG_ENDED.

create a image copy of your shadow.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
shadowBuilder.onDrawShadow(canvas);
```

Create as ImageView with this bitmap and add to the root view of your view hierarchy.

Then you create Animator to move this back to the original position and remove the ImageView.

```
ObjectAnimator defaultChangeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder((Object)mImageView,
                pvhLeft, pvhTop, pvhRight, pvhBottom);
```